# Implementing combination lock, but cannot figure out how to implement a turning knob

Tags: c++, locking, combinations

So essentially, I am trying to create a program that simulates a combination lock.

Instructions: You are asked in this assignment to specify, design, implement and test a class that can be used in a program that simulates a combination lock. The lock has a circular knob, with the numbers 0 through 39 marked on the edge, and it has a three-number combination, which we will call x, y, z. To open the lock, you must turn the knob clockwise at least one entire revolution, stopping with x at the top; then turn the knob counterclockwise, stopping the second time that y appears at the top; finally turn the knob clockwise again, stopping the next time that z appears at the top. At this point you may open the lock. Your lock class should have a constructor that initializes the three-number combination (use 0, 0, 0 for default arguments).

Also provide member functions to:

1. Alter the lock’s combination to a new three-number combination.
2. Turn the knob in a given direction until a specified number appears at the top.
3. Close the lock.
4. Attempt to open the lock.
5. Inquire the status of the lock (open or shut).
6. Tell you what number is currently at the top.

Code is below:

```
// Lock_Outline.cpp : This file contains a combination lock outline.
//
//CONSTRUCTORS for the Combo_Lock class:
//   Combo_Lock(int x = 0, int y = 0, int z = 0)
//      Precondition: All three lock sections must start at 0.
//      Postcondition: The lock must be able to be opened with the right combination.
//MODIFICATION MEMBER FUNCTIONS for the Combo_Lock class:
//   void AltCombo(int x, int y, int z)
//      Postcondition: These three values are able to be changed.
//   void TurnKnob(bool Dir, int NumClicks)
//      Postcondition: The direction and number for the 3 numbers must be able to be entered in.
//CONSTANT MEMBER FUNCTIONS for the Combo_Lock class:
//   GetLockStatus(()
//      Postcondition: The lock is either open or closed.
//   GetCurrentNumber()
//      Postcondition: The number turned to must be returned.


#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

    class Combo_Lock
    {
    private:
        int  State = 0;                     //State 0 (first number) State 1 (Second number) State 2 
(Third and last number)
        int  NumClicks = 0;            //Number of clicks (0-39) as we would see on a combination 
lock)
        bool LockStatus = false;  //Indicate if the lock is open or locked.
        void OpenLock();                //Opens the lock if we successfully entered the three numbers 
correction 
        void ClosedLock();             //Close the lock and set the State to 0 awaiting the first 
number once again
    public:
        //CONSTRUCTORS
        Combo_Lock(int x = 0, int y = 0, int z = 0);   //Constructor with a default combo of 0, 0, 0
        //MODIFICATION MEMBER FUNCTIONS
        void AltCombo(int x, int y, int z);                      //Method to changes the combination
        void TurnKnob(bool Dir, int NumClicks);   //Enter direction and number for 1st, 2nd, and 3rd 
number
        //CONSTANT MEMBER FUNCTIONS
        bool GetLockStatus();                                            //See if lock is open or 
closed
        int  GetCurrentNumber();                                   //Return the current number we 
turned to
    };

    void Combo_Lock::AltCombo(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        int x1 = x;
        int y2 = y;
        int z3 = z;
    }



    Combo_Lock::Combo_Lock(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        AltCombo(x, y, z);
    }

    int main()
    {
        int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
        int state = 0;
        Combo_Lock Lock1(3, 4, 6);  // I set the combo to 3,4, and  6.  

        cout << "Enter the first number.\n\n";
    
        cin >> x;

           assert(x == 3);

           if(x == 3)
              {
       
                  cout << "\nThis is correct.\n\n";
              }

        cout << "\nEnter the second number.\n\n";

        cin >> y;
       
           assert(y == 4);
           if (y == 4)
              {
        
                  cout << "\nThis is correct.\n\n";
              }


        cout << "\nEnter the third number.\n\n";

        cin >> z;

  
           assert(z == 6);

           if (z == 6)
              {
             cout << "\nThe lock has been opened.\n\n";
              }

    
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
        void Combo_Lock::OpenLock()
        {
        void OpenLock();
        }
```

Comment: Just decide what a turn in a direction does, eg clockwise increments the number, anti-clockwise decrements the number.

Comment: There are widgets that already exist that perform your functionality.  You may have to pay for them.

Comment: Hey Adrian. I guess I thought it was more complex than that. I'm still not 100% sure if that's the only thing I need, but if your suggestion works, I guess I'll answer my own question or something.